Image Not Received in Push Notification for Flutter iOS App
I'm working on a Flutter app and trying to display push notifications with images on iOS devices. While the notifications are received, the image does not appear. I have set up the Notification Service Extension and configured Firebase Messaging, but the image is still not displayed in the notifications.
What I've Tried:

Ensured the Notification Service Extension is set up and configured correctly.
Updated the Info.plist file with necessary permissions.
Checked the image URL and ensured it's accessible.
Tested on real devices with different iOS versions.

Despite these efforts, the image still does not appear in the notifications.

Note: The image size must be under 300 KB.
check this :- https://medium.com/@akhil-ge0rge/implementing-image-push-notifications-in-flutter-with-firebase-for-ios-android-aaa1cc1120eb

Did you make sure the key of image url has matched between server and client side?, also just try with some other images with different size and type (jpg, png...)

didn't worked, is there any other solution


Add Notification Service Extension in iOS
The Notification Service Extension is responsible for downloading and attaching images to the push notifications. This step is crucial for displaying images.
Steps to Add Notification Service Extension:

Open your iOS project in Xcode (ios/Runner.xcworkspace).

Add a Target:
•    Go to File > New > Target.
•    Select Notification Service Extension and click Next.
•    Name it (e.g., NotificationService) and click Finish.

Update the Deployment Target to match the main app (e.g., iOS 15.5).
 import UserNotifications
 import UIKit
 class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {
 override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, 
 withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) 
 -> Void) {
 guard let bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? 
 UNMutableNotificationContent) else {
 return contentHandler(request.content)
 }

 if let imageURLString = request.content.userInfo["media-url"] as? 
 String,
 let imageURL = URL(string: imageURLString) {
 downloadImage(from: imageURL) { imageAttachment in
  if let attachment = imageAttachment {
      bestAttemptContent.attachments = [attachment]
 }
 contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
 }
 } else {
 contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
 }
 }

private func downloadImage(from url: URL, completion: @escaping 
(UNNotificationAttachment?) -> Void) {
let task = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) { 
(downloadedURL, _, _) in
guard let downloadedURL = downloadedURL else {
return completion(nil)
}

do {
let attachment = try UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: 
url.lastPathComponent,
url: downloadedURL,options: nil)
completion(attachment)
} catch {
completion(nil)
}
}
task.resume()
}
}





Send Basic Notification Payload
         {
         "to": "<device_token>",
         "notification": {
         "title": "Notification Title",
         "body": "Notification Body"
          },
         "data": {
         "media-url": "https://example.com/image.jpg"
         }
         }

Flutter code receive notification:
        FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
        if (message.data.containsKey('media-url')) {
        String imageUrl = message.data['media-url']!;
        showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        title: Text(message.notification?.title ?? 'Notification'),
        content: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
        Text(message.notification?.body ?? ''),
        Image.network(imageUrl),
        ],
        ),
        ),
        );
        }
        });

